# How to download File name contains Single quote Special character using ASP.NET C# Web form

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my existing application file name contains Single quote **(')** Special character  EXample file name:  **Zahed's.doc**. When I am trying to download this file I am not able to download because the file name is contained  **'s** .

Below is my uploading design code:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="textfield_new1" />
```

My uploading .cs Code:

```
bo.Para21 = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();//ResumePath
string FinalFileName = Convert.ToString(Sno) + bo.Para21;
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"] + "Resumes/" + FinalFileName);
```

Below is my Downloading file design code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_ResumeUpload" runat="server" CssClass="cv_heading" OnClick="lnkbtn_ResumeUpload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Button click for Dowloading code:

```
 protected void lnkbtn_ResumeUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string path = lnkbtn_ResumeUpload.Text;

    string ResumePath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResumePath"].ToString();

    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel1, this.GetType(), "SCRIPT", "window.open('"+ResumePath+path + "')", true);

 }
```

My issue is already 800 users are uploaded with the file name 's and I am not able to download that application, how to resolve this type of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the generated javascript will be broken because it will be:

```
window.open('...Zahed's.doc');
```

So the '-character will break your script. Easiest solution is to replace ' with " in your code on the window-open part:

```
 System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel1, this.GetType(), "SCRIPT", "window.open(\"" +ResumePath + path + "\")", true);
```

Comment: Then why we are using \ and I will check and update my answer. @Esko

Comment: If you want "-character inside a string you need to escape it with \ in c#

Comment: Hi Esko I got another Issue for this file name : Up_dmd.imzhadk@gmail.com_In_zahed's resume´.doc  is not downloading, please check and confirm. @Esko

Answer (score 1):

Try to encode the filename using HttpUtility.UrlEncode()

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx

**Example:**
If your filepath is called "path" you need to encode it first, then send it to javascript.

```
string filePath = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path);

System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel1, this.GetType(), "SCRIPT", "window.open('"+ filePath + "')", true);
```

Another solution is **HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode** which encode your javascript string completely that contains apostrophe.

Comment: Can you update your according to above question code. @Navid Kh